# Operand should contain 1 column error in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my mysql query. Does anyone know what the error is and how to fix it?

Thanks.

```
SQL query: Documentation

INSERT IGNORE
INTO thread_user (thread_id,user_id,last_read_date)
SELECT 24,1,NOW()
UNION
SELECT 24, b.a, NOW()
FROM (SELECT (2,3,4) AS a) b

MySQL said: Documentation
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Comment: What is `(SELECT (2,3,4) AS a)` supposed to do?

Comment: Create a table of 1 column called a, and rows are 2, 3, 4. This query above is a result of php code running on user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want three rows in the second subquery.  The expression `(2, 3, 4)` is causing the error.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO thread_user(thread_id,user_id,last_read_date)
    SELECT 24, 1, NOW()
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 24, b.a, NOW()
    FROM (SELECT 2 as a UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 UNION ALL
          SELECT 4 
         ) b;
```

This is just a guess on your intentions.  Note that the outer `UNION` can be `UNION ALL` -- you should always use the latter unless you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: This works, but I can further simply it by separating the selects into

`INSERT IGNORE INTO thread_user(thread_id,user_id,last_read_date)
    SELECT 24, 1, NOW() UNION
    SELECT 24, 2, NOW() UNION
    SELECT 24, 3, NOW() UNION
   SELECT 24, 4, NOW()`